# How to calculate the decimal point offset from 0

Tags: javascript

I'm having a bit of a go slow in the brain department today and thought maybe somone had done this before.

Given the numbers below, what simple means could I use in Javascript to work out the decimal point as a number, eg:

- 1 = Decimal point: 0
- 10 = Decimal point: 1
- 1678 = Decimal point: 3
- -0.56 = Decimal point: -1
- -0.0045 = Decimal point: -3

Comment: Your question doesn't make sense. First you say "offset from 0" then you actually show offset from 1.

Comment: Unless you mean 10^0 or something..

Comment: I guess am trying to say 'where integer is 1-9, call that the zero base', ie: no decimal point

Comment: Some missing data points: what do you expect to receive as a result for 0.25 or -123? If -1 and 2, respectively, then @mbeckish has your answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

log(x)/log(10) // log base 10 of x

Need absolute value if you want to pass negative numbers for x.

Need floor if you want integer result.

Example:

Math.floor(Math.log(Math.abs(-0.56))/Math.log(10));

Answer (score 0):

It's not entirely clear what your algorithm is. What makes -0.56 decimal point -1 and not -2? Similarly, does the sign of the original number matter to the sign of the decimal point?

You can take the log base 10 of the absolute value of the numbers, then truncate to the integer to get the "decimal point" and get all of the results shown above. But, there are a number of algorithms that will do so within the provided set while diverging on other numbers.

Comment: Fair point. To give some context, its less so a matter of mathematical precision as it is working out number ranges for display purposes on the Y Axis of a dynamic chart. The decimal arrived at drives the measure of Y Axis step increments